# Issue with duplication of model instance using save()

Tags: django

I have following models:

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    # some fields

class EmployeeHistory(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # some fields
```

I want to record new `EmployeeHistory` as soon as `Employee` instance was created.

```py
employee = Employee(
  # some fields are filled
)
employee.save()

history = EmployeeHistory(
  employee=employee,
  # some fields are filled
)
history.save()
```

In this case I have two same recently added `Employee` records. I've tried to remove `employee.save()` but have `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'employee'`. How could I save both of these instances without duplication of `Employee`?

Comment: I don't think the problem is here. The code you have shared will not create duplicate entry

Comment: There is nothing wrong in code you have uploaded. I just checked in my project. Check other parts of code.

Comment: @ruddra, I've tried to print all of the employees just after ```history.save()``` and there was duplication

Comment: did you override any of the save methods of `Employee` or `EmployeeHistory`? Or do you have any signals works based on either of models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def post_save_employee_reciever(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            EmployeeHistory.objects.create(employee=instance)
        except:
            pass


post_save.connect(post_save_employee_reciever, sender=Employee)
```

You can use a post save signal as shown above, so when ever an Employee instance created, it will create an instance of EmployeeHistory